# Pandas DFs and find missing columns filled with NAN in each

Tags: pandas

df, df2 and df3 as an example with some overlapping columns.

```
    >>> df
   A  B  C
0  3  4  3
1  1  1  4
2  4  4  4
3  2  3  2
4  1  0  3

>>> df2
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  2
1  3  3  2  3
2  0  0  1  1
3  0  0  1  1
4  1  0  2  2

>>> df3

   A  B  C  D  F
0  2  2  0  1  1
1  4  3  3  0  3
2  0  4  0  0  0
3  0  2  2  1  0
4  4  2  4  1  1
```

find those missing columns and added them to each df with NAN values

expected results:

```
    >>> df
   A  B  C D  F
0  3  4  3 nan nan
1  1  1  4 nan nan
2  4  4  4 nan nan
3  2  3  2 nan nan
4  1  0  3 nan nan

>>> df2
   A  B  C  D F
0  1  0  2  2 nan
1  3  3  2  3 nan
2  0  0  1  1 nan
3  0  0  1  1 nan
4  1  0  2  2 naa
```

df3 as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `reindex`

```
df=df.reindex(columns=df3.columns)
df
Out[18]: 
   A  B  C   D   F
0  3  4  3 NaN NaN
1  1  1  4 NaN NaN
2  4  4  4 NaN NaN
3  2  3  2 NaN NaN
4  1  0  3 NaN NaN
```

Update

```
l=df.columns.tolist()+df2.columns.tolist()+df3.columns.tolist()
df=df.reindex(columns=set(l))
```

Comment: what don't know which df is intact ? complete columns will be those unique?

Comment: we can use align here :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for [`DataFrame.align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html):

```
df1, _ = df1.align(df3)
df2, _ = df2.align(df3)
```

```
df1

   A  B  C   D   F
0  3  4  3 NaN NaN
1  1  1  4 NaN NaN
2  4  4  4 NaN NaN
3  2  3  2 NaN NaN
4  1  0  3 NaN NaN

df2

   A  B  C  D   F
0  1  0  2  2 NaN
1  3  3  2  3 NaN
2  0  0  1  1 NaN
3  0  0  1  1 NaN
4  1  0  2  2 NaN
```